# Change the name of the output log file

Tags: logging, log4net

I am trying to modify the output name that is defined by appender in "Sitecore.config"

`<file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt"/>` specifically `{date}`

Every time I start a new instance of Sitecore, during the same day it creates a new file with different processID.

`example:
log.20161214.txt
log.20161214.123456.txt
log.20161214.484151.txt
log.20161214.789914.txt`

I would like to have all the logs for that one day to be in one `"log.yyyDDmm.txt"`.

Is there a way to modify a log4net output? Or maybe there is another solution?

I am using Sitecore 8.1

Comment: Are you sure in your examples? SitecoreLogFileAppender at the and of the file adds formatted DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"), not processID. ProcessID will be set only if you add to file {processid}.  See methods GetTimedFileName and OpenFile of SitecoreLogFileAppender

Comment: It adds some kind of information to the logs after the date. I am only specifying {date}.

Comment: `
<appender name="AuditLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
   <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/audit/audit.log.{date}.txt" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
   </layout>
   <encoding value="utf-8" />
 </appender>
`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a `RollingFileAppender` instead of the default Sitecore one and configure it to roll by date.

You can find samples in the [log4net config examples section](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender) of the documentation.

Specifically with Sitecore, change the appender(s) to the following:

```xml
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```

- `file` : The name of the file to log to. Note that we supplement this using below settings.
- `rollingStyle` : The format to roll each file on. This causes a new file to be generated per day.
- `datePattern` : The suffix to add to the file each time it is rolled. Note that the file extension is included here in single quotes. See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255588/661447) for more details.
- `staticLogFileName` : If set to true then the latest log file will always have the same name, but note that due to your `file` value there is no file suffix so the would just be called **log** with the above settings.

The files will now be generated in format **log.yyyMMdd.txt**.

Comment: This solution just creates one instance of the file, if I restart SiteCore nothing is being added to the file file. Is there a reason for this?

This is what I had originally: <appender name="AuditLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
   <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/audit/audit.log.{date}.txt" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
   </layout>
   <encoding value="utf-8" />
 </appender>

Comment: Looks like you've added a new appender. Did you also register the logger in `<root>`? Alternatively, to replace the existing appender make sure the `name` attribute matches the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `log4net.Appender.FileAppender`

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

For Minimal locking with FileAppender you can use something like below

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="${TMP}\log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And as a suggestion, RollingFileAppender works better for most scenarios. If your requirement is to have unified view of all log files for a particular category you can try [Sitecore Log Analyzer](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx) module from marketplace

And to know more on what other appenders are available check this [link from log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

Seems someone has covered this, and shows where sitecore adds the process id
https://sitecore.unic.com/2015/01/27/create-a-single-sitecore-log-file-per-day

However worth considering why sitecore adds the process id to the log file if it already exists 
http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/log4net-thread-safe-but-not-process-safe/17
When IIS recycles with overlapped recycling (default), there could be two processes trying to write to the same file, and then the second process won't log anything. 
So maybe it's not a bad idea to have the process id in the file name, as more important that logging works than in same file.